# What does love mean in the true sense?

Tags: meaning-of-life

I feel love is not just about enjoying each other's company. It's more
about caring for the other person and always longing to see them
happy. But in this endeavour to see them happy, we tend to get hurt
most of the times. Is it true that we can love any other person only
when we stop loving our-self?

Is there a discussion in ethics that essentially argues that the love of self should be subjugated to the love of the other?

Comment: I think that Aristotle's discussion of what a friend is is a pretty good take on what love is, supposing it to be true that "a friend loves at all times."  He says that a friend is someone who will do what they believe to be in your best interest, for your own sake.  Seemingly Aristotle doesn't make any normative statements about whom you should befriend, though.

Comment: From my point of view, love means Squaring the Circle problem, where solution reconcile Circle and Square, where Circle means 0 and Square means 1, where 0 and 1 means False and True, respectively. I wrote an article about that. Sharing as is, maybe can be of [help.](https://medium.com/@gvitalie/zero-is-odd-or-even-number-9472f489bf94) Any mathematical formula is an expression of Love, because it is a hypostasis of Knowledge as Truth.

Answer (score 1):

First note that there are different *kinds* of love:

> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love

Secondly, how would you quantify love? Is it simply there or not, or is it measurable along a continuous scale?

> https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9891

Notwithstanding, consider parental love primeraly being expressed in caring for a child. The parent **need** to take care of themselves, or risk leaving the child destitute. Similarly the happiness of a loved one is rarely served by neglecting one's own happiness.
In short, there is a strong case for:

**Love yourself before you can love another.**

Answer (score 1):

Love has depth. Love means to hug someone.Love means to kiss someone. Love means to be constantly mindful of someone. Love means to sacrifice yourself for someone else. Love means to constantly care for someone. Love means no hatred, not a little bit of hatred. Love means friendship. Love means joy in other’s success. Love means surrender.

Answer (score 0):

We human beings care about other people's opinions on us: The majority of people will not obtain their self-esteem by a personal belief that they are consistent with their idealistic image for themselves, but rather by other people approval and confirmation. For example, if my idealistic self is nice and kind, therefore i want other people to see me so, but if my idealistic self is violent, therefore i want other people to see me as so.

From this perspective, when i love someone, this means that i'm completely sure that he sees me as i want to be seen and does not see me as i do not want to be seen.

This need for approval could seem subjective or trivial, but no it is not, that's because the urge for self-esteem is universal.

Comment: interesting answer, thanks. this loveless person would see it inverted, though, that i see him as he wants

Comment: [Oh](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/44212/the-love-song-of-j-alfred-prufrock), do not ask, “What is it?”
Let us go and make our visit.

In the room the women come and go
Talking of Michelangelo.

Comment: i would like to upvote this twice, i find it quite beautiful tbh

Answer (score 0):

From a systemic-interactive point of view, love is a common interaction. Nevertheless, its mechanism is commonly misunderstood.

An interaction is an exchange of something between two entities. There are two parts: what the subject receives, and what the subject delivers (you are the subject because you are assessing the interaction, and she's the object of love).

The most common notion of love is *love as receiving*. The subject gets attention, care, sex, etc. It cannot be controlled, ergo, it is a passive form of love. It does not require nothing, it is egoistic, and tends to enforce self-esteem. People commonly thinks of this variant as the meaning of love. Sadly, if the subject is focused on this perspective, love will dissappear for sure. It is not really an interaction, so, the object could soon get tired of giving and not receiving.

The other perspective is love as giving. Of course, this is absolutely controllable, it is an active form of love, and it requires effort. It does not give nothing to the subject, nothing, except the pride of giving. It is not easy to perform, requires patience and constance. Of course, the object of love will feel pleased.

But here's the magic of human interaction: any action creates a tension, and our human nature demands us to relieve tensions in order to survive. So, if you give love, the other person will feel good, and if she's a normal, sane and mature person, will feel grateful. Gratefulness can be relieved only by mirroring the action, that is, performing an equivalent reaction.

The consequence of this natural behavior causality is obvious: if the subject receives love and returns less than received, the object will soon lose interest and the interaction will end. On the contrary, if the subject gives more than received, the object will get permanently engaged in the relationship.

But wait, you don't need to wait until receiving something to start reacting. You can be the causal generator. You can start giving and always give more than received (at a certain point, you will feel that her life is more important than yours, that's just part of the process, but it does not imply stop loving oneself: just having a lower priority than the other). As said, if she's mature, love will never end. Eureka, that's the real recipe for love: choosing a sane and mature interacting partner, and always give more than received. In fact, that's the same recipe for economic development and any other interaction. You can find all this on my last book.

Answer (score 0):

Love is care, or rather love incorporates care, at a minimum.

> many find caring about your beloved for her sake to be a part of what
> it is to love her. The robust concern view of love takes this to be
> the central and defining feature of love

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/love/

Romantic love depends on intimacy to work, if not to exist

> The three components of love in the triangular [psychology] theory of love are
> intimacy, passion, and decision/commitment (Sternberg, 1986).

and in its truest sense I'd have thought it exists independently of everyone else, including who you are kidding.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> "Subtle degrees of domination and servitude are what you know as love
>
> But love is different it arrives complete just there like the Moon in
> the window
>
> Like the Sun of neither East nor West nor of anyplace
>
> When that Sun arrives East and West arrive
>
> Desire only that of which you have no hope seek only that of which you
> have no clue
>
> Love is the sea of not-being and there intellect drowns
>
> This is not the Oxus River or some little creek this is the shoreless
> sea; here swimming ends always in drowning
>
> A journey to the sea is horses and fodder and contrivance but at
> land’s end the footsteps vanish
>
> You lift up your robe so as not to wet the hem; come! drown in this
> sea a thousand times
>
> The Moon passes over the ocean of non-being
>
> Droplets of spray tear loose and fall back on the cresting waves
>
> A million galaxies are a little scum on that shoreless sea"
>
> -'Subtle Degrees' by Jalal al-Din Rumi

> "So come, my friends, be not afraid
>
> We are so lightly here
>
> It is in
> love that we are made
>
> In love we disappear"
>
> -Leonard Cohen